# Node 14 ECMAScript Modules: Import Modules without File Extensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

Is it possible to import ECMAScript modules *local to my project* without using a `.js` or `.mjs` file extension using Node's native  ECMAScript modules support?

In other words -- if I have a directory structure that looks like this

```
index.mjs
src/some-file/index.mjs
```

I can import `some-file/index.mjs`

```
// File: index.mjs
import {someSymbol} from './some-file/index.mjs'
```

but I'm unable to do either of the following

```
import {someSymbol} from './some-file/index'
import {someSymbol} from './some-file'
```

Without resorting to bundling/transpiling/etc. or publishing a package, is there any way I can `import` a local javascript file without specifying the file extension?  Or will local imports always have a file extension? I've tried [reading through the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) on this and have found them --- ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation about [Mandatory file extensions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions)

You can fix this was with the esm package. This package active experimental-modules.

`npm i esm`

Use:
`node -r esm index.js`
instead of just node index.js

Answer (score 0):

`import` works in upper versions of node, like node 15 as listed here: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Be mindful that some contents are still experimental.

You can still use `const var = require()`.